# Injecting DataAccess layer class not allowing to call Controller method

Tags: .net, api, service

I am injecting data access layer to write automated unit testing for Datalayer . I am using web api and Dependency injection. We are using Microsoft Enterprise library

```
    public class DataLayerClass : IDataLayerClass
    {
        Database database;
        public Data Layer Class(Database getdatabase)

        {
            database = getdatabase;
        }
    }
```

This is not allowing to call controller method getting below error.

> "Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see
>   the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this
>   exception for details."

Comment: Where is the HTTP request ? @Gautam Kumar

Comment: I am running my api service and passing input parameter .URL is like http://localhost:56641/Help/Api/GET-METHODCall . Because of this change , Injecting Data access layer . We are getting Http error when running the api service

Comment: did yu try to call your API from PostMan ?

Comment: Yes  i got the solution. Database in microsoft enterprise library is abstract class and i am injecting this which is not creating instance. Because of this getting exception